# Australia: How to know price of goods in groceries

Tags: australia, shopping, price

I am currently visiting Australia (Sydney to be more specific) and I can't figure what is the price of different goods in the grocery stores. It seems there are no prices next to the items and no price printed on the packages.

Is there a way to tell how much something costs before buying it?

Comment: Not sure what that is.  We visited two different ones.  The last one is quite popular - city convenient or something of the sort

Comment: I find this question confusing as I've never had any trouble determining the price of items in Australia. Can you perhaps illustrate what you're referring to with a photo?

Comment: Hmm photo of what? There are shelfs with different goods on them e.g. spring water of different types, juices, chocolate and so on. And there are no prices anywhere, not on the shelf(as is usual in Europe) and not on the product.

Comment: Sounds like you've visited convenience stores. Go find a Woolworths or Coles.

Comment: @pnuts In Australia, you call it a $2 shop.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev What Greg Hewgill is trying to say is that Australians are not used to seeing shelves without prices (myself included) and because it is so unusual a lot of people have never seen it. Hence he requests a photo. I come from Western Australia and I have never seen shelves without prices...

Comment: @That would be the Australia Tax.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australia_Tax

Comment: I dislike questions that are more of a complaint or rant - and that based on incomplete information or very minimal experiences - posing as an actual question.

Comment: I've decided to vote this up. Australia is expensive and it's easy to get passively ripped off when you are a new arrival. Convenience stores with the word "supermarket" in their name prey on naive tourists so it's very easy to fall for in touristy areas. The good news is that even in city centres you can now find at least "express" big chain supermarkets, which was not the case when I was growing up there.

Comment: @JoeBlow it is not a complaint. I have 4 types of water I have never heard of and I have no idea how much each of them costs. I have no idea what is the typical way to indicate an item's price in Australia. This is my first visit here. Also I had no idea what is a convenience store(I thought it is a type of supermarket).

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev A convenience store is a small store selling a few basic items of food, sweets, newspapers, tobacco and things like that. Think of the kind of shop that you get at a gas station. In many European countries, they're often kiosks on the street. A larger convenience store might be similar to a very small supermarket.

Comment: @DavidRicherby thank you. I deduced that from the answer/comments. In Bulgaria usually the prices in those are close to supermarkets(definitely not 2.5x) and they should always indicate the price of each good.After I visited my first two shops(both convenience stores apparently) I thought having prices is not common practice here in Australia. The answer really helped me.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev All businesses in Austalia ***MUST display the full price*** of all items they sell. (https://www.accc.gov.au/business/pricing-surcharging/displaying-prices) or (https://www.accc.gov.au/consumers/prices-surcharges-receipts/price-displays). I suggest talking to the ACCC or informing the person behind the counter / owner that they are braking the law.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect you are not visiting actual grocery stores, but **convenience stores**, which often have wildly inflated pricing and poor signage to hide that pricing.  These are often named things like "Kings Wharf Supermarket" (actual example which I will not dignify with a link), but supermarkets they're not.  Add the exact address of the last shop you visited in a comment if you want to confirm.

Look for the nearest [Coles](https://www.coles.com.au/), [Woolworths](http://woolworths.com.au), [Aldi](https://www.aldi.com.au/), or [IGA](http://www.iga.com.au/) instead, and you will find all prices *very* clearly labeled, plus often half or less of what the convenience store wants:

[image]

Obviously there are not so many of these in the Sydney city centre, because they're large and need a lot of expensive real estate, but you can find one within a few blocks if you use the store locators.  For example, [this large Woolies](https://www.woolworths.com.au/Shop/StoreLocator/NSW-Sydney-1248?utm_source=GooglePlaces&utm_medium=organic&utm_campaign=GooglePlaces&utm_content=NSW-Sydney-1248) is right next to Town Hall.

Comment: imagine paying "3.50" for fake wonder bread.  life is sad.

Comment: This is "good bread" for people who don't like actual good bread like you get in Europe - that stuff is much harder to get and much more expensive in Australia. The cheap white bread is really awful. Anyway Wonderbread is fake bread or that's a fake use of the word fake d-:

Comment: @JoeBlow Helga's actually the better stuff as far as industrial bread goes.  If you want Wonderbread simulacra, Coles has that too, and it's only $0.85 a loaf: http://shop.coles.com.au/online/national/-5377163p

Comment: *"Helga's actually the better stuff as far as industrial bread goes"* I suppose that is true my friend on the face of it.  But it makes it easy to think something like *"After all Hitler wasn't as bad as Stalin!!!"*   You've made me think, the "quality" industrial breads are perhaps more insidious - it's rather like, oh, corporations "greenwashing" you know. If you've ever created products or worked in advertising, you'll know that "Ben & Jerry's!" is exactly the same filth as other mass Ice Confections, with a "hand! drawn!" label printed on the front.

Comment: @pnuts yes that's the one

Comment: @pnuts Prices will either be listed on little stickers stuck on the product, or simply unlisted so you need to ask staff.

Comment: @pnuts it was not the entire shop but many products did not have any prices. Now that I've spent a lot more time in Australia I know that in supermarkets it is very different. However in convenience shops like the first two I visited there were no prices anywhere on many products. I checked this several times.